# Building a list of options with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ObservableCollection> property that I would like to display in a list box in a WPF window using the MVVM model.  Ideally I would like to have a listbox that has a check box for the bool and a label for the string and when the user changes the value of the checkbox it would change the corresponding bool.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idealy, if you want to follow the MVVM approach, everyone of your elements in the ObservableCollection should be a ViewModel.

These viewModels should expose 2 properties, such as `string Description` and `bool IsSelected`.

All you need then is to provider your ListBox with a Style in order to display a checkbox and textblock for each databound ViewModel.

The following XAML implements such a Style. Note: The usercontrol DataContext should hold a ViewModel containing an `ObservableCollection<YourClass> Items { get; set; }` property where YourClass exposes `string Description { get; set; }` and `bool IsSelected { get; set; }`. You will obviously want to throw in some `INotifyPropertyChanged` magic in there.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="itemChoix" Margin="5,5,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource BoxBorder}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxListStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Comment: This looks really good, give me a little while to try and implement a solution.

Comment: I'm 90% of the way there.  I have the main viewmodel that has the ObservableCollection<CheckBoxListItem>.  Then CheckBoxListItem is a viewmodel that has public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isSelected;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isSelected = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
When I check a check box it sets the IsSelected, but how do I get it to run a method that is located in the main viewmodel?

Comment: Can't you just call your method in the IsSelected setter?

Answer (score 3):

Try using an ItemsControl, and don't bind to a list of checkboxes, define a model:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourModelList}">
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
            </StackPanel>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public ObservbleCollection<YourModel> YourModelList { get; set; }
```

And the Model:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged as necessary

Comment: I seem to get an exception when starting the app up.  'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.' Line number '128' and line position '23'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your public ObservableCollection property in your ViewModel
2. Create an IsSelected bool property.
3. Populate collection from constructor or command.
4. Create a command for the checkbox that sets the IsSelected property.
5. Do the Xaml binding